# mongoDB - average on array values

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to compute an average aggregation operation on each values of an array for each documents in my collection.

```
Document structure

{
   myVar: myValue,
   [...]
   myCoordinates: [
      myLng,
      myLat
   ]
}
```

So, I tried to compute average of **myLng** and **myLat** values of **myCoordinates** array for the whole collection of documents by querying the collection like this :

```
myColl.aggregate([{
   $group: {
       _id: 0,
       lngAvg: { $avg: "$myCoordinates.0" },
       latAvg: { $avg: "$myCoordinates.1" }
   }
}])
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't work and returns me a value of 0 for both **lngAvg** and **latAvg** fields.

Have you some ideas? Is this feasible at least?

Comment: I think you need to $unwind the document first

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Positional notation in aggregation seems to still be unsupported, [check out this ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4589?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel).

As @Sammaye says you'd need to either unwind the array first, or replace your coordinates array with an embedded `lng`/`lat` embedded doc, which would make this trivial.

Given the array structure, you might unwind and project the lat/lng like this:

```
myColl.aggregate([
 // unwind the coordinates into separate docs
 {$unwind: "$myCoordinates"},

 // group back into single docs, projecting the first and last
 // coordinates as lng and lat, respectively
 {$group: {
   _id: "$_id",
   lng: {$first: "$myCoordinates"},
   lat: {$last: "$myCoordinates"}
 }},

 // then group as normal for the averaging
 {$group: {
   _id: 0,
   lngAvg: {$avg: "$lng"},
   latAvg: {$avg: "$lat"}
 }}
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I could adjust my query with yours and it works! :)

Unfortunately, I couldn't use a document for the `lng`/`lat` couple since I use a 2d geo index on it.
I was worried about loosing any reference to the root document by using the unwind operator on the array but it seems it returns a copy of the root document for each value contained in the array by replacing the array by each value.

I hope they'll fix positional notation in aggregation soon to simplify aggregation operations on 2d geo index.

Comment: [According to the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/#multi-location-documents-for-2d-indexes), geospatial indexing should already work on `lng`/`lat` embedded docs.