# mongodb average arrays across many documents

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb

Using mongodb, I have a collection of documents where each document has a fixed length vector of floating point values such as below:

```
    items = [
        {"id": "1", "vec": [1, 2, 0]},
        {"id": "2", "vec": [6, 4, 1]},
        {"id": "3", "vec": [3, 2, 2]},
    ]
```

I would like to take the row wise average of these vectors. In this example I would expect the result to return

```
[ (1 + 6 + 3) / 3, (2 + 4 + 2) / 3, (0 + 1 + 2) / 3 ]
```

This answer is very close to what I am looking for, but as far as I can tell it will only work on vectors of size 2. [mongoDB - average on array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302495/mongodb-average-on-array-values)

An answer has been provided that is not very performant for large arrays. For context I am using ~700 dimension vectors.

Comment: Please check my answer, I'm curious to know how it would perform on such large arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work: https://mongoplayground.net/p/PKXqmmW31nW

```
[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      a: {
        $push: {
          $arrayElemAt: ["$vec", 0]
        }
      },
      b: {
        $push: {
          $arrayElemAt: ["$vec", 1]
        }
      },
      c: {
        $push: {
          $arrayElemAt: ["$vec", 2]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      a: {
        $avg: "$a"
      },
      b: {
        $avg: "$b"
      },
      c: {
        $avg: "$c"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Which outputs:

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "a": 3.3333333333333335,
    "b": 2.6666666666666665,
    "c": 1
  }
]
```

Here's a more efficient without $avg operator. I'll leave other answer up for reference.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/rVERc8YjKZv

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      a: {
        $sum: {
          $arrayElemAt: ["$vec", 0]
        }
      },
      b: {
        $sum: {
          $arrayElemAt: ["$vec", 1]
        }
      },
      c: {
        $sum: {
          $arrayElemAt: ["$vec", 2]
        }
      },
      totalDocuments: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      a: {
        $divide: ["$a", "$totalDocuments"]
      },
      b: {
        $divide: ["$b", "$totalDocuments"]
      },
      c: {
        $divide: ["$c", "$totalDocuments"]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: This answer technically works, but it appears to have pretty poor runtime for large dimension vectors. I am running the aggregation on search its that match about 10-50k documents with vector sizes ~700 dimensions. 

I needed to pass allowDiskUse set to true in order to complete the calculation.

Any way to speed this up?

Comment: Yes I should have given more consideration to the size of you collection. I posted some tweaks, the first answer is creating massive arrays in order to use mongos $avg operator. The second answer simply sums each row-wise vector value and performs the averaging manually. Your execution time will still increase as your collection size increases since you are still scanning every doc but this will drastically cut down memory usage and should cut execution time as well.

Comment: The edits work well. 

I ultimately need to find another solution as far as i can tell though. We're actually using aws documentdb which appears to throw errors about limitations doing aggregations of more than 45 fields. I have not been able to find any documentation of how to modify these limits. The performance on 45 fields is very slow as well compared to real mongodb. (I was using a mongodb docker image locally for testing)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$unwind` to get values into separate documents, the key is to keep the index of the values. Then you can use `$group` by the index and calculate the average using the `$avg` operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$vec",
      includeArrayIndex: "i" // unwind and keep index
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$i", // group by index
      avg: { $avg: "$vec" }
    }
  }, // at this stage, you already get all the values you need, in separate documents. The following stages will put all the values in an array
  {
    $sort: { _id: 1 }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      avg: { $push: "$avg" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lDblYPsyl0n)